# Can wpf program running in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: wpf

I hava an idea that if wpf program can running in Raspberry Pi?

How to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Not a WPF app, but UWP, on Windows 10 IoT Core on a Pi 2 or 3.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your answer.Whereas it seems like UWP program not so stable,even microsoft's edge browser.